# Installing 5505 Wireless Mobile Broadband module in to Dell E6410

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-latitude, 3g, mobile-broadband

I have a dell E6410 from work which I want to put a Dell Wireless 5505 mobile broadband card into from my old XPS M1210.  I've moved the hardware over and the E6410 can see it but when I try running either Dell Mobile Broadband Manager or Utility programs they are reporting that the hardware is not present, even though the device status is "The device is working properly".  To note that I have a working sim card installed.

When installing the hardware, there are two small wires although only one place to attach a single wire on the WWAN module - I've tried with both wires with the same outcome.

Given that I believe the hardware is working fine, as it works fine in the XPS M1210, does anybody know if the hardware is compatible?  or if it is, what drivers I would need to get it working?

Comment: Hello, 
I'd the same issue, I've run the Dell Wireless 5505 mobile broadband card with dell E6410 under linux so hardware is compatible, but unfortunately there isn't any Connection Manager released by Dell for the modem and laptop. I’ve run the modem under windows as well, just by adding manually drivers form my an old laptop (D630). I’m able to start connection as a system modem and it works, but without APN configurations I’m additionally changed by GSM provider. Still looking for final solution under Windows.

Comment: please share your findings! same 5505 chip on a latitude D620 here...